# Spark and Parquet Predicate Pushdown for daily deltas

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, parquet, predicate

A data warehouse has been proposed that is based on Spark on AWS (probably Glue ETL but possibly EMR) where partitions are by day (yyyy, mm, dd) and the data for each table is based on an initial snapshot, with daily deltas uploaded into the partitions.  The data will be stored in Parquet files.

The deltas will contain only the columns that have changed.  Between Spark and Parquet Predicate Pushdown, it has been asserted that partition scans will not be required.  However, from my research it appears to me that Predicate Pushdown won't really help in this case, because if you create a "WHERE" clause based on the partition that says simply "give me the most recent" column value, Spark will still have to start scanning the latest partition and work it's way back until it finds a column value.

In fact, it seems to me that columns that haven't changed in a while will be the poorest query performers.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Bad approach. Eithef all snapshors of all deltas or snapshot with begin and end positions daily and deltas.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but a little more detail would really help.  Thx.

Comment: For reporting and DWH (imho) you measure how well the design is based on how easy the querying / semantic layer for query generation is. Doing the suggestion you  make is the most complicated approach. DWH etc. is all about denormalization, making things easily additive etc.

Comment: Thank you, I agree completely, and in fact we have a longer term plan to address this shortcoming.  I'm attempting to confirm my contention that Predicate Pushdown wouldn't even help in this use case.  I believe that we're in agreement that it wouldn't.  I'm hoping that someone will confirm my understanding of why (given my question).

Comment: Te question is a little hard to follow I have to say.

Comment: Basically, it was presented that because of Predicate Pushdown Spark/Parquet would be able to find the latest value for a column without doing partition scans.  I don't believe so because it's a chicken and egg problem; you can't create a WHERE clause that eliminates daily partitions because you don't know which partition contains the latest value for a given table value.  I still don't know if that was a good explanation ;-)

Comment: I don't see how it can work.  I think you would have to partition by 'current'  An approach I have used is to keep two copies of the data, one only current and the other with change data capture begin/end as thebluephantom mentioned.  Not recommending that.  Ideally you can make scanning all history to get current fast.

Comment: Functionally it's a bad approach. Parquet is columnar, but your point is correct.

Comment: You may wish to look at databricks delta for inspiration on approach.  They use 'versioned' parquet.  https://databricks.com/product/databricks-delta

Comment: Did you resolve this?